# Shiny Selectinput for every non-numeric column of a Filteinput data

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a Shiny dashboard where:
1) The user selects an excel file
2) A `Selectinput` option is created for every non-numeric column of the obtained dataframe is created that gives users the option to select every unique value in this column. This is how my code looks so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      fileInput('datafile', 'Choose xlsx file',
                accept = c(".xlsx")),

      lapply(names("varselect"), function(i) {
        selectInput(paste0(i), paste0(i),
                    choices = "varselect"[i],
                    multiple = TRUE,
                    selected = "")})),
    mainPanel()))


server <- function(input, output,session) {
    Data <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      return(data.frame())
    }
    read.xlsx(infile$datapath, 
              sheetIndex = 1) %>% select_if(colSums(!is.na(.)) > 0%>% select_if(~!is.numeric(.x)) %>% head()) 

  })

  output$varselect <- renderUI({

  })


  observe({
    lapply(names(Data()), function(i) {
      selectInput(paste0(i), paste0(i),
                  choices = Data()[i],
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  selected = "")})})


}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am aware of the fact that the code is not working and that there are some grave mistakes, but I hope that somebody can help me to find an approach that does work for this problem. I am rather new to Shinny and that is why i honestly have no clue how to solve this problem.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ui`, you can include a `uiOutput` which will contain all of the dynamically created `selectInput` widgets.

Then, in `output$varselect` you can create the `selectInput` based on the number of columns in `Data()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('datafile', 'Choose xlsx file',
                accept = c(".xlsx")),
      uiOutput("varselect")
    ),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Data <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      return(data.frame())
    }
    read.xlsx(infile$datapath, sheet = 1) %>%
      select_if(colSums(!is.na(.)) > 0) %>%
      select_if(~!is.numeric(.x)) %>%
      head()
  })

  output$varselect <- renderUI({
    if (ncol(Data() > 0)) {
      lapply(1:ncol(Data()), function(i) {
        selectInput(inputId = paste0("si_", i), 
                    label = paste0("Input #", i),
                    choices = Data()[,i],
                    multiple = TRUE)
      })
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```